# How can I use Typescript React code snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed Typescript React code snippets into my VS code. In the description of the plugin there is written how to install it and list of snippets.

> Below is a list of all available snippets and the triggers of each one. The ⇥ means the TAB key.

but there is not written how to use the snippets.

I tried to write  `tsdrpfc login_page` into the VS code terminal and expecting a new component will appear, but got error message`tsdrpfc: command not found` instead.  How can I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start to write the shortcut in the file e.g.  tsdrpfc  and then press CTRL + SPACE

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to use the snippet in the terminal. Instead you want to create a new .ts/.tsx file and then type your snippet and hit tab there. It will auto generate the boilerplate for the corresponding snippet.